# Laravel + Bootstrap - navbar links doesn't redirect

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-3

I've got trouble with this.

I updated database with example data and navbar got broken. I don't know what cause a problem - maybe you will help me.

So, when I want to go to page "News" or "Projects" nothing happend - just like link had "#" value.

```
     <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

  <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ URL::base() }}">devprj*</a>
  </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="{{ URL::base() }}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ URL::to('news') }}">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ URL::to('product') }}">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="./forums">Forums</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ URL::to('about') }}">About</a></li>
          @if ( !Auth::guest() )
          <li><a href="{{ URL::to('admin') }}">Panel</a></li>
          @endif
      </ul>

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        @if ( Auth::guest() )
          <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" href="{{ URL::to('login')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
          <a class="btn btn-success navbar-btn" href="{{ URL::to('register')}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Register</a>
        @else
        Welcome, <strong>{{ HTML::link('admin', Auth::user()->username) }} </strong> |
            {{ HTML::link('logout', 'Logout') }}
        @endif
      </ul>

    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
```

Everything works fine exept stuff within navbar-collapse . What's wrong?

I can post more stuff, If that can help.

Bootstrap 3 + Laravel 3.

//pmache

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML output? Thats what is needed to determine what the issue is.

Comment: full index output: http://pastebin.com/mr42kPAk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is the `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute on the...

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
```

Remove it, and everything should work.

`data-toggle="collapse"` should only be added to the elements that trigger the collapse event (buttons), and not the elements that are the target of the collapse.

Comment: I didn't notice that. Good eye!